# Deleting Records based on relationship to other two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have three tables in MySQL, `table1`, `table2` and `table3`. table2 has foreign key of table1 while table3 has foreign key of table2 but not from table1. Structure is something like this:

table1

```
Name   | type
------------------------
d_id   | int
d_name | varchar(100)
```

table2

```
Name   | type
---------------------------------------
s_id   | int
d_id   | int (foreign_key table1 d_id)
s_name | varchar(100)
```

table3

```
Name    | type
----------------------------------------
m_id    | int
s_id    | int (foreign_key table2 s_id)
m_value | int
```

I can easily select and join the information on these three tables but to delete base on similar join I just don't know how to do. This is how I did to select data.

```
SELECT * FROM table3 
JOIN table2 ON table3.s_id = table2.s_id 
JOIN table1 ON table2.d_id = table1.d_id
```

Now, I want to delete some values on table3 where table3 = table2 = table1 how do I do that?

Comment: Just like `SELECT`, you can do a `DELETE` by using the `JOIN` on the appropriate keys. If you are having problems, please share the `DELETE` query and SO will help you in rectifying the query.

Comment: thanks, will get back to this will just check it out.

Comment: @AniketV added the select statement I used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you want to delete data from `Table3` which is not reference by any foreign key, I'm using dummy data to demonstrate this query. Note, you should only have problems when deleting data from `Table1` and `Table2` which is reference by foreign keys, You can't delete data from master table without deleting its reference from child tables as `Primary and Foreign key` forces a `Referential Integrity` constraint.

```
create table table1
(
d_id    int PRIMARY KEY
,d_name  varchar(100)
);


create table table2
(
s_id    int PRIMARY KEY
,d_id    int 
,s_name  varchar(100)
,FOREIGN KEY (d_id) REFERENCES table1(d_id)
);

create table table3
(
m_id     int PRIMARY KEY
,s_id     int 
,m_value  int
,FOREIGN KEY (s_id) REFERENCES table2(s_id)
);

insert into table1 values (1,'D1');
insert into table1 values (2,'D1');
insert into table1 values (3,'D1');

insert into table2 values (10,1,'S1');
insert into table2 values (11,2,'S2');
insert into table2 values (12,3,'S3');

insert into table3 values (100,10,23);
insert into table3 values (101,11,34);
insert into table3 values (102,11,45);
insert into table3 values (103,12,54);

select * from table3;

DELETE T3
FROM  Table3 as T3 INNER JOIN Table2 as T2 ON T3.s_id = T2.s_id
                   INNER JOIN Table1 as T1 ON T1.d_id = T2.d_id;

--All the Records from Table3 will be deleted now, add where clause in above
--Query to limit your delete.

select * from table3;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you've happily written a select statement that selects the list of IDs that should be deleted, you can then delete those rows:

```
DELETE FROM sometable WHERE ID IN 
(
  SELECT idcolumn FROM othertables JOIN otherothertables WHERE blahblah ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM table3 t3
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON t3.s_id = t2.s_id
INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t2.d_id = t1.d_id
WHERE t3.s_id=t2.s_id AND t2.d_id=t1.d_id
```

Comment: User is requesting to delete rows from table3 only.

Comment: Thanks for sharing but I'm not sure but won't this delete all values in all three tables? I want to delete only values at t3 but not from all the tables.

Comment: No, it won't. When you say `DELETE FROM table3`, only the row in _table3_ will be deleted.

Comment: Updated the query, this should do what you want

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to delete all data  from `table3` which corresponds to `d_name=fdiengdoh` in `table1`, you can use below query.

```
DELETE FROM table3 as t3
inner join table2 as t2 on t3.s_id = t2.s_id
inner join table1 as t1 on t2.d_id = t1.d_id
AND t1.d_name = 'fdiengdoh'
```

If you need to remove all corresponding data, just remove the last line from above query.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I tried this, and got an error: Unknown column table2.s_id in where column